# How do I access dateClickInfo in FullCalendar React

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

Let's say I have the following:

```
dateClick={this.handleDateClick}
```

and

```
handleDateClick = (arg) => {
    this.setState({ modalShow: true });
    alert(arg.dateString)
  };
```

The alert gives me undefined. How do access the dateClickInfo Object inside the handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You spelled it wrong.

Its `arg.dateStr` not `arg.dateString` according to docs [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react)

By referencing `dateString`, you are trying to get something that doesn't exist.